# Determine if a type has particular member function signature

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, stl

```
template<typename U> struct CheckSignature {
    enum {SizeTrue = 1, SizeFalse = 2};
    typedef char ReturnTrue[SizeTrue];
    typedef char ReturnFalse[SizeFalse];
    typedef typename U::iterator (U::*InsertSig)(typename U::iterator, typename const U::value_type &);
    static ReturnTrue &CheckInsert(InsertSig);
    static ReturnFalse &CheckInsert(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(CheckInsert(&U::insert)) == sizeof(ReturnTrue));
};

int main() {
    CheckSignature<std::string >::value; //compile error
    CheckSignature<std::vector<int> >::value; // OK
    return 0;
}
```

This code generates a compile error for the string class saying that none of the 2 overloads could convert all argument types. However, for vector it compiles fine. Shouldn't overload resolution choose CheckInsert(...) whenever the parameter isn't of type InsertSig?

Comment: what compilation error do you get?

Comment: @Tim error C2665: 'CheckSignature<U>::CheckInsert' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: What's your `InsertSig`?

Comment: It's the following pointer-to-member-fuction: `typedef typename U::iterator (U::*InsertSig)(typename U::iterator, typename const U::value_type &);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename U> struct CheckSignature {
    enum {SizeTrue = 1, SizeFalse = 2};
    typedef char ReturnTrue[SizeTrue];
    typedef char ReturnFalse[SizeFalse];
    typedef typename U::iterator (U::*InsertSig)(typename U::iterator, typename U::value_type const &);
    template <InsertSig f> struct dummy_type { };
    template <typename T>
    static ReturnTrue &CheckInsert(T*, dummy_type<&T::insert> dummy = dummy_type<&T::insert>());
    static ReturnFalse &CheckInsert(...);
    static const bool value = (sizeof(CheckInsert(((U*)0))) == sizeof(ReturnTrue));
};

int main() {
    if(CheckSignature<std::string >::value) {
      std::cout << "String class has proper insert function" << std::endl;
    }; //OK, does not print, as expected.
    if(CheckSignature<std::vector<int> >::value) {
      std::cout << "Vector class has proper insert function" << std::endl;
    }; //OK, does print, as expected.
    return 0;
}
```

The reason why it doesn't work is because, in your version, taking the address of the insert function will fail at the call site, not at the substitution (which is not an error). The above will make sure that if the type U (templated to T) cannot be used to obtain a member function pointer to insert which is convertable to the given signature, it will fail to substitute for the dummy parameter, and thus, revert to the ellipsis version.

Comment: that compiled for me, but `::value` was always false.

Comment: ah, in VisualStudio, vector::insert signature takes a `const_iterator` -- not an `iterator`.  Once I changed the `InsertSig` typedef, it worked for me.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the ambiguity was with the various overloads of the insert() function, not CheckInsert(). Thanks!

Comment: I'm noticing this fails with map and set. It seems to do with the fact that those member functions are inherited. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yeah, that's a classic problem. There is a discussion on that on the boost mailing list: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Using-SFINAE-to-detect-presence-of-member-function-Unreliable-td2586695.html

Comment: So it appears there is no solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `std::string::insert` doesn't take a `const char&` parameter, but just a `char`.

Also, depending on how far the implementation has has come in its C++11 support, all containers might use a const_iterator (instead of iterator) to indicate the position.